# link not clicked because removed after onblur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea with this event bind :
**on focus :**
display a link that will popup a larger version of text area.
**on blur :**
remove the link.

but "click" event on the link never triggered because it's already removed when **onblur** trigerred.

```
$("#text-area-new-message").focus(function(){
    $("#text-area-new-message").after('<a id="enlarge-text-area" href="#">enlarge text area</a>');
    $("#enlarge-text-area").click(function(){
        alert('test');
    });
});
$("#text-area-new-message").blur(function(){
    $("#enlarge-text-area").remove();
});
```

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EPzbR/1/)

how is the better way to do that?

Comment: Why do you remove the link? why not just hide it?

Comment: i want to create a function to dynamically add this behavior to random textarea

Answer (score 0):

When the user leaves the textbox, you could delay the removal of the link  by, say, a few seconds:

```
$("#enlarge-text-area").delay(3000).remove();
```

Or more. Whatever seems an appropriate amount of time for a user to click the link if that was their intention. This could get even more 'clever', by, for instance, fading out slowly and stopping the animation and subsequent removal only if it captures the mouse (by way of hovering on the link.)

Comment: It doesn't work, `remove` doesn't use the animation queue. [Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/EPzbR/3/)

Comment: Ah, yes, could be as simple as adding a quick fadeout, then.

Comment: @roasted Another possibility, yes.

Comment: Anyway, hard-coding a number is always a bad solution. if there are others of-course.

Answer (score 0):

one approach is to use jquery on function to attach event handlers to all 'future' 
'#enlarge-text-area'  elements :

$('#myParentDiv').on('click', '#enlarge-text-area', function(){});

other approach is to hide rather than remove the link.